# Get path of here document as a file

Tags: shell, here-document

I have a program that takes input from an `XML` file whose path is specified as a parameter. I want my shell script to be self contained, so a here document seems like the right way to go. Unfortunately, this program doesn't accept input from `STDIN`, so piping wouldn't work.

I've read that here-docs are implemented as files in `/tmp`, so that leads me to think there might be a way.

Is there a way to inline my XML file within my shell script, and get a path for it that this xml parser could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your shell supports process substitution (bash, zsh, ksh88, ksh93), you could use:

```
your_command <( cat <<EOF
contents of the
xml file
EOF
)
```

The whole `<(...)` part connects the output of the `cat <<EOF` command to a FIFO which is then passed as an argument to the current command.

But I think the more portable way would be, to just create a temporary file with the contents and delete it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

How a shell implements here-documents differ between shells, and what gets used behind the scenes may vary depending on runtime factors.  The `bash` shell, for example, tries to use a pipe internal to the shell process for documents shorter than the system's pipe size.

You can access the standard input stream by reading from `/dev/fd/0` or `/dev/stdin` on most Unix systems. These are not guaranteed to be available, but most commonly available Unix systems implement them today.

Using one of these pathnames to provide your command with a pathname and, at the same time, providing data on its standard input stream should solve your issue.

```bsh
thecommand /dev/stdin <<'END_XML'
Some XML document
goes here.
END_XML
```

Using `/dev/stdin` like this would work as long as your command does not need to seek in the given file. If it does, you may want to write the input to an actual file temporarily instead:

```bsh
tmpfile=$(mktemp) || exit

cat <<'END_XML' >"$tmpfile"
Some XML document
goes here.
END_XML

thecommand "$tmpfile"
rm "$tmpfile"
```

---

Using a here-document along with one of these special pathnames is a convenient way of providing ephemeral input to other commands as well, as in

```bsh
sed -f /dev/stdin file <<'END_SED'
Some sed script
goes here
END_SED
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Ironically in @chaos's `cmd <(cat << EOF...)` the `<(...)` typically expands to one of those `/dev/fd/x` special files, but the data ends up going through an extra redundant pipe.

Answer (score 1):

"Here" documents can very well be read by the interpreter from the source being interpreted and fed into the command getting the input (that's what I'd do, anyway, to avoid hassle of fooling around with temporary files). In any case,whatever mechanism is used seems not to be documented, and thus can change at any time. And in particular, there is no guarantee a different shell you are getting as e.g. `/bin/sh` will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the `-` shorthand for stdin with heredocs like this

```bsh
command - <<EOF
<file>
  <contents />
</file>
EOF
```

Comment: No all commands interpret `-` as meaning standard input. OTOH, on most systems, you can use `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0` for that.